# Two UITableView in one UIViewController problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I considered to use two `UITableView` in one `UIViewController` which is also do data source for them but encountered the problem that while both tables visit `numberOfRowsInSection` only one visit `cellForRowAtIndexPath` at the start and both tables contain empty rows.

Do someone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIViewController containing 2 UITableViewControllers instead, and you won't have this problem.